# implement switch in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to implement alternate to switch functionality in Python.

Example:

```
>>> def f(x):
        return {
            'report/1/client_1_2001.txt':'10.7.0.151 -> 10.7.0.152',
            'report/1/client_1_3001.txt':'10.7.0.151 -> 10.7.0.153',
        }.get(x,'No mapping')

>>> f('report/1/client_1_3001.txt')
'10.7.0.151 -> 10.7.0.153'
```

I have written a separate function which prints all the combinations

```
def msg():
    for x in range(1,9):
        for j in range(1,9):
            if x == j:
                continue
            else:
                print "'report/%s/client_%s_%s00%s.txt':'10.7.0.15%s -> 10.7.0.15%s'"%(x,x,j,x,x,j)
```

I am calling above function inside another function

```
def f(x):
    return {msg()}.get(x,'No mapping')
```

When I am trying to access the value with this:

```
print f('report/2/client_2_1002.txt')
```

I see this error:

```
    return {msg()}.get(x,'No mapping')
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Can someone let me know if I am missing anything here?

Comment: What are you expecting `get` to do there?  You created a set.  Sets don't provide any way to get specific items.

Comment: Is there anyway I can substitute the value of msg() function in same format just like printing the output? so that I don't need to write all the stuff in def f(x) function, my goal is to get `'10.7.0.151 -> 10.7.0.153'` when I execute `f('report/1/client_1_3001.txt')` as shown in above "Example".

Comment: Modify `msg` to build a dict instead of print a bunch of stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify `msg` to build a dict instead of print a bunch of stuff.

```
def f(x):
    return getmsg().get(x,"No mapping")
def getmsg():
    d = {}
    for x in range(1,9):
        for j in range(1,9):
            if x == j:
                continue
            else:
                d['report/%s/client_%s_%s00%s.txt' % (x,x,j,x)] ='10.7.0.15%s -> 10.7.0.15%s'%(x,j)
    return d
```

Resulting in:

```
>>f('report/1/client_1_3001.txt')

'10.7.0.151 -> 10.7.0.153'
```

Or avoid the nested call to `f` and `getmsg` and require an argument in the `getmsg` function:

```
def getmsg(val):
    d = {}
    for x in range(1,9):
        for j in range(1,9):
            if x == j:
                continue
            else:
                d['report/%s/client_%s_%s00%s.txt' % (x,x,j,x)] ='10.7.0.15%s -> 10.7.0.15%s'%(x,j)
    return d.get(val,"No mapping")
```

Outputs:

[image]

NB: It seems redundant to rebuild this dict every time you call the function, and there are probably better ways to do this. :)

One way you might do this (and I am by no means an expert with python) is by instantiating a `Class` which contains the mapping. This way, we build the mapping `dict` in the `__init__` procedure so that no matter how many times we request the mapping, we aren't rebuilding the dict every time.

```
class Map():
    def __init__(self):
        self.mapping = self.getmapping()
    def find(self,x):
        return self.mapping.get(x,"not mapped")
    def getmapping(self):
        d = {}
        for x in range(1,9):
            for j in range(1,9):
                if x == j:
                    continue
                else:
                    d['report/%s/client_%s_%s00%s.txt' % (x,x,j,x)] ='10.7.0.15%s -> 10.7.0.15%s'%(x,j)
        return d
```

use it thusly:

[image]

Comment: Thanks much @David!

Answer (score 1):

Change your `msg` to return a dictionary:

```
import itertools as it

def msg():
    return {'report/{x}/client_{x}_{y}00{x}.txt'.format(x=x, y=y):
            '10.7.0.15{x} -> 10.7.0.15{y}'.format(x=x, y=y)
            for x, y in it.product(range(1,9), repeat=2) if x != y}
```